Ensure that dotnet Tasks are stopped when they go out of garbage collector scope
I have a background task that I am modeling with a Task and which is stopped with an IAsyncDisposable.
// implementation
public sealed class Worker : IAsyncDisposable
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts;
    private readonly Task _worker;

    public Worker()
    {
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _worker = DoWork(_cts.Token);
    }

    public ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
        _cts.Dispose();
        return new ValueTask(_worker);
    }

    private static async Task DoWork(CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            do async work
        }
    }
}

static async Task CorrectUsage()
{
    await using var worker = new Worker();

    do more stuff
}

static async Task IncorrectUsage()
{
    var worker = new Worker();

    do more stuff
}

Under normal circumstances this works fine, however, there seems to me to be a memory leak here which might occur if the calling code does not dispose of the worker. If the Worker component is being misused, I would like the GC to kill the running task when a it goes out of scope with a _cts.Cancel() call
I have read about ~Worker() and Dispose(bool disposing), but all of the documentation I have found points to these methods being specifically for the disposal of unmanaged resources.

Q1: How can I get the GC to call _cts.Cancel()
Q2: If the answer includes usage of Dispose(bool disposing), is there any documentation on how this would be called with disposing: false?

A note on Tasks and the GC
Can .NET Task instances go out of scope during run?

Quick question - have you tried making DisposeAsync() asynchronous, and awaiting the task? this would ensure the task has finished, and then you can conclude the Dispose method

My question is regarding a scenario where DisposeAsync is not called. So, the DisposeAsync method is just there for completeness. Added an edit to make that more clear

Where's the actual task created? Only works is an active tasks here, everything else is syntactic sugar needed by the async/await machinery. This isn't about disposal of work, it's about exiting the loop, which can only happen if your code deterministically disposes Worker. There's no leak, that's how this code is written to work

@Panagiotis Kanavos, check the "IncorrectUsage()" method (which is a new edit). In this scenario, the task will never complete, which is a memory leak

It's not a memory leak, it's a bug in the code. You explicitly designed Worker to terminate the loop, not task, when Dispose is called. That means you must call Dispose. You'll have to rethink this design and stop calling it a Task - it's not. It won't even run in the background unless work itself is an actual async operation or the result of Task.Run

I would like to focus the discussion more on how to prevent this "memory leak bug" using the GC finalizer. Is this possible? I don't want to go into reasons why, the context is too complex for an SO question

If instead of deriving from IAsyncDisposable you derived from BackgroundService or IHostedService then the DI middleware itself would take care of calling StopAsync to stop the loop in the ExecuteAsync method. Now though, it's the caller's responsibility

@Shane you're asking the wrong question, using invalid terms, about problems caused by the code design. It's very simple and no matter of arguing will turn Worker into a Task or forgetting to call Cancel into a memory leak

DI is not involved here. Think of the Worker as something much simpler and generic like a List<>. I might have 100s or 1000s of them in process at the same time. How resource intensive are background tasks?

@Shane and even asking about the finalizer shows a misunderstanding of GC - when the GC runs and calls the finalizer there's NO guarantee that any of these managed objects is still alive. If the finalizer tries to call _cts it may find it's dead

@Shane think of that's a .NET Framework 1 BackgroundWorker without progress . How resource intensive are background tasks? there's no foreground and background Task. There are CPU-bound tasks like those created by Task.Run that use the CPU, and async tasks that are triggered when something signals them to complete, like IO terminating. It's not a matter of you making me understand how GC or tasks work. As for workers - Parallel.ForEachAsync over an IAsyncEnumerable, possibly one produced by a Channel is a great way to process infinite streams of incoming messages concurrently

@Panagiotis Kanavos "finalizer tries to call _cts it may find it's dead": actually no, it won't. The running thread/Task will keep a reference to it and keep it alive; "forgetting to call Cancel": this is a philosophical argument about expectations in unmanaged vs managed enviroments. We should not discuss here; "How resource intensive are background tasks?": apologies, I meant to say "How resource intensive are BackgroundServices". None of this work is CPU bound. Threads are not a good fit, Tasks are

They're lightweight because they're nothing more than implementations of the IHostedService interface, which has StartAsync and StopAsync methods called by the runtime.

You're trying to argue that StopAsync (that's what this DisposeAsync does) should be called automagically and the fact that doesn't work is a leak. IDisposable or IAsyncDisposable don't hook into the GC infrastructure, they're meant for application code to call for deterministic disposal. Not garbage collection.

@Panagiotis Kanavos "should be called automagically" yes that is the crux of it; "the fact that doesn't work is a leak": when memory cannot be freed, that is a leak, no matter what the reason is; I have looked into BackgroundServices, and they just rephrase the problem: "how do I make sure stop async is called if a dev misuses the component". I feel I have to add context now: this Worker component is a type of list. It is not a service, it is not DI'd, it is up to whatever developer is using it to new one up. There is scope to introduce a factory to DI, which would solve this indirectly


How can I get the GC to call _cts.Cancel()?

Like this:
public sealed class Worker : IAsyncDisposable
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    ~Worker()
    {
       _cts.Cancel();
    }

    public ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
        _cts.Dispose();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        return new ValueTask(_worker);
    }
}

The _cts.Cancel() throws an exception if the _cts is disposed. The line GC.SuppressFinalize(this) ensures that the ~Worker finalizer will not be called, preventing this exception.
As a side note, this DisposeAsync() implementation exposes asynchronously the exception of the _worker task, if any. This is against the collective wisdom of the C# community, according to which the Dispose/DisposeAsync shouldn't throw exceptions.

I should address also a question that you didn't ask, which is whether there is anything fundamentally wrong with calling _cts.Cancel() in the finalizer. There might be. I can't guarantee you with 100% confidence that it's fine. Quoting from Chris Brumme's article "Finalization":

One of the guidelines for finalization is that a Finalize method shouldn’t touch other objects. People sometimes incorrectly assume that this is because those other objects have already been collected. Yet, as I have explained, the entire reachable graph from a finalizable object is promoted.
The real reason for the guideline is to avoid touching objects that may have already been finalized. That’s because finalization is unordered.
So, like most guidelines, this one is made to be broken under certain circumstances. For instance, if your object “contains” a private object that is not itself finalizable, clearly you can refer to it from your own Finalize method without risk.

This article was written at a time when .NET 2.0 was still in the making (February 20, 2004), but contains basic principles that probably still apply. What I am deriving from the quoted text is that:

It is not possible for the _cts to be recycled (have its memory reclaimed) when the ~Worker finalizer runs, because the _cts is part of the finalized Worker's reachable graph.
It is possible for the _cts to be already finalized (have its ~CancellationTokenSource finalizer invoked) when the ~Worker finalizer runs. AFAICS the current implementation of the CancellationTokenSource class (.NET 8) doesn't include a finalizer. In case you are using an earlier version of the .NET platform, you may want to find and study the CancellationTokenSource implementation of your targeted .NET version. As long as the CancellationTokenSource doesn't have a finalizer, the probability of the _cts.Cancel() throwing an exception is greatly reduced. I can't guarantee that the probability is zero, because there might by other finalizable objects, related to the specific APIs that you are using, that might still hold a reference to the _cts when the _cts.Cancel() is called, and these objects might be already finalized. You could consider enclosing the _cts.Cancel() in a try block with an empty catch block, to minimize the impact of this scenario. According to an answer by Hans Passant, that describes the behavior of .NET 2.0:


An exception in a finalizer is fatal. The default CLR host terminates the app for any unhandled exception.

I should add another word of wisdom from Chris Brumme's article:

It’s hard to implement Finalize perfectly.


Looks good. I'll run some experiments and try to get it to fail. Otherwise seems like a simple solution (will mark as accepted if I can't find a failure case)

@Shane the only thing that bothers me, because my experience with finalizers in minuscule, is the possibility of the _cts being recycled by the GC before the Worker instance that owns it. I would guess that the garbage collector recycles abandoned objects in the correct order, taking into account the references between them, but I am not 100% sure.

I think I can get around that by making the code a bit more complex. I can pass the CTS into the DoWork method so that it will not be recycled until DoWork completes. I just need to figure out how to get the status of the Task _worker (reference type) by using a value type, and use the status as a proxy for "_cts might be cleaned up". But that is far too hacky a question for SO

@Shane interesting question: Destructor execution order? Quote: "If Object A has a reference to Object B and both have finalizers, Object B might have already been finalized when the finalizer of Object A starts." So it seems that my assumption in my previous comment was wrong.

@Shane but you are right, the DoWork task keeps the _cts rooted. So it's only a problem if the task completes before the Worker is finalized by the GC. In which case the ~Worker might run after the _cts has been recycled. And I don't know how the GC behaves in this scenario.

_cts may well be recycled by the time the finalizer runs. That's why finalizers are only meant for cleaning up unmanaged resources. And even if the CTS isn't recycled yet, the task or objects it uses may be recycled. The OP wanted someone to say the finalizer is OK from the start, but it's just not

That means the finalizer can throw exceptions that can't be handled by the application, forcing its termination.

@PanagiotisKanavos thank you for your comments. I edited the answer and added some information from an article by Chris Brumme, that I found in an article by Eric Lippert. At this moment my opinion is that calling _cts.Cancel() in the finalizer is somewhat dangerous, but the level of danger might be controlled (reduced) through study and experimentation.
